# making pstree() last process child

Tags: c, sleep, wait, fork

I'm trying to get pstree() function as last process child but can't seem to do it.

My code:

```
int i, pid;

int mainPid = getpid();

for(i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
        sleep(1);
        exit(0); 
    }
}


if(fork() == 0) {

    char a[100];
    sprintf(a, "%d", mainPid);
    execlp("pstree", "pstree", "-c", a, NULL);

}else { 
    sleep(1); 
}
```

i get:

```
t1─┬─pstree
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   └─t1
```

but I would like something like this:

```
t1─┬─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   ├─t1
   └─pstree
```

I also tried puttting the last process to sleep for atoi(argv[1]) but it didn't help :(

Comment: You do realize that processes on the same level of pstree are in alphabetic order?

Comment: I didn't know that. So ther is no possible way to change that unless I rename the program with something alphabeticli after pstree?